# Check which submenu item was clicked in context menu strip

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu

There is a ContextMenuStrip in a grid control.

I have named it as GridContextMenu.

The GridContextMenu is populated with 4 - 5 items using the following code :

```
 gridcontextMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem
                        {
                            Name = Plants,
                            Text = Plants,
                            Tag = Plants,
                            Width = 100,
                            Image = <image source is put here>
                        });

gridcontextMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem
                        {
                            Name = Animals,
                            Text = Animals,
                            Tag = Animals,
                            Width = 100,
                            Image = <image source is put here>
                        });
```

For the animal menu in tool strip, i added submenu in the following way

```
(gridcontextMenu.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Tiger", image_source, new EventHandler(SubmenuItem_Click));
(gridcontextMenu.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Lion", image_source, new EventHandler(SubmenuItem_Click));
(gridcontextMenu.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Elephant", image_source, new EventHandler(SubmenuItem_Click));
```

In the SubmenuItem_Click event handler i need to know which animal submenu was clicked.

How to achieve this ?

currently i have the code for event handler in the following way :

```
private void SubmenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

How to check condition in this event that which animal submenu was selected ?
Kindly share the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private void SubmenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem; 
    var menuText = clickedMenuItem.Text;

    switch(menuText) {
        case "Tiger":
           break;

        case "Lion":
          break;
         . ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is helpful, Thanks Tigran

Answer (score 4):

As I found that none of the other answers worked here, I went digging and found the proper solution. This may have been applicable only in .NET Framework 4+ but here is what I found to work.

Essentially, the `ItemClicked` event in the `ContextMenuStrip` control passes itself as the sender and a `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs` object when the event is raised. As you can't obtain the clicked item from the ContextMenuStrip itself, the only way to obtain this information is to interrogate the `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs` object and the clicked item resides in there as a `ToolStripItem` object. This can then be used to extract the name of the option to use in an if/switch statement as appropriate. See below:

To configure the EventHandler:

```
...
contextMenuStrip1.ItemClicked += OnContextMenuItem_Clicked;
...
```

To handle the event and retrieve the text of the clicked item:

```
private void OnContextMenuItem_Clicked(object sender, ToolStripMenuItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripItem clickedItem = e.ClickedItem;
    string itemName = clickedItem.Text;
    ...
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone looking for this answer in future :)

Comment: Much less convoluted way to get item of ContextMenuStrip; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Tag` for this purpose in case when your should localize your application.
Moreover `Tag` is an object so you can put any tapy of data there. For example `Enum` type.

```
private void SubmenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem; 
    EnumType item = (EnumType)clickedMenuItem.Tag;

    switch(item) {
        case TigeItem:
           break;
        case LionItem:
          break;
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to retrieve the ToolStripMenuItem's index if you have created the ContextMenuStrip Dynamically. It is really helpful with getting Enum values. My Context menu is dynamically created and filled with the Enum Names. I hope it helps someone. Sorry for the formatting still new to posting.

```
  `private void DynamiallyCreatedContextMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

        var parent = (item.Owner as ContextMenuStrip);

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (item == parent.Items[i])
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: This, except instead of the `for`-loop you can just do `var index = parent.Items.IndexOf(item);`

Answer (score -1):

```
private void SubmenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    string clickedItemName=e.ClickedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!